# NHibernate: DeleteById using HQL does not remove entity from session cache

Tags: nhibernate

I wanted to implement `DeleteById` method with NHibernate. I did it through extension method as below:

```
public static void Delete<TEntity>(this ISession nhSession, object id)
{
    var queryString = string.Format("DELETE {0} WHERE id = :id", typeof(TEntity));
    nhSession.CreateQuery(queryString)
            .SetParameter("id", id)
            .ExecuteUpdate();
}

public void DeleteById<T>(Guid id) where T : BaseEntity
{
    nhSession.Delete<T>(id);
}
```

This works great; no problem. But I observed that this is not changing the statistics of session.

I load an entity in memory using `Get` method. Then, I delete it with `DeleteById`. But `nhSession.Statistics.EntityCount` returns same count before and after calling `DeleteById` method.

I have other method also to delete record as below:

```
public void Delete<T>(T instance) where T : BaseEntity
{
    nhSession.Delete(instance);
}
```

This is NOT extension method and this DOES NOT use `HQL`. This updates `nhSession.Statistics.EntityCount` properly. Before call, count is 1 and after it resets to 0 which is expected.

So what does this mean? HQL does not update session level cache? Or it just does not update `Statistics`?

Are there any drawbacks using `DeleteById` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are using is called

#### [13.3. DML-style operations](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#batch-direct)

> As already discussed, automatic and transparent object/relational mapping is concerned with the management of object state. This implies that the object state is available in memory, **hence manipulating (using the SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements: INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) data directly in the database will not affect in-memory state**....
>
> ...

Farther reading will show delete example

> To execute an HQL DELETE, use the same IQuery.ExecuteUpdate() method:
>
> ```
> ISession session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
> ITransaction tx = session.BeginTransaction();
>
> String hqlDelete = "delete Customer c where c.name = :oldName";
> // or String hqlDelete = "delete Customer where name = :oldName";
> int deletedEntities = s.CreateQuery( hqlDelete )
>         .SetString( "oldName", oldName )
>         .ExecuteUpdate();
> tx.Commit();
> session.Close();
> ```

Comment: So this means it will not update session cache. right? That also means it will create problems in other part of program. correct? Refer my other question for similar problem. http://stackoverflow.com/q/41545279/5779732    What is good solution then?

Comment: I am not sure if I could comment: *"...it will create problems in other part of program..."*. Simply **DML** was intended to help us with BULK editing, **without loading** data from DB to app tier. We can think about it as a Stateless session. So, DML should not create problems, if it is used for [ACID operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID)... outside of any `ISession` assumptions. And that should be part of answer: "...What is good solution then..."*. Use this kind operation as isolated statement... any session should be lasting just before or after that... hope it helps a bit